# Confused by the task given (involves identical inequality of functions)

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

The task says:

> Show that if some function $\;f(z)={1\over g(z)}$, where
>   $g\not\equiv0$ is an       entirely analytic function, then the
>   isolated singularities of $\;f$ are exactly zeros of $g$ and namely
>   are the poles, that have the same orders as the orders of the
>   corresponding zeros of $g$.

As I understand it correctly (relying on what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar) says) the notation $g\not\equiv0$ means that $g$ is never equal to $0$, that means for any $z$, which would be the same if we said that $g$ doesn't have zeros. But the taks asks us to prove that these not existing zeros are the singularities of $\;f(z)$.

Is there something wrong with my knowledge of mathematical notation or with the taks itself?

Comment: No, $g \not\equiv 0$ means that $g$ is not identically zero. `It is also used for "identical equality" of functions;`

Comment: @DanielFischer so when we write $f(x) \equiv g(x)$, that means $f=g$ for all $x$, but when we use the notation $f(x) \not \equiv g(x)$ it doesn't mean $f(x) \not = g(x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: $f \not\equiv g$ means there is at least one $x$ with $f(x)\neq g(x)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so translating this notation into English, that means "$f(x)$ not for all $x$ equals $g(x)$"

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks you're helping me 2nd day in a row :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation means that the function $g$ is not identically zero.  This means that $g(z) = 0$ for all $z$ does NOT hold.